# az vm run-command failed

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I am using az vm run-command invoke to run ansible-playbook on Azure Linux RHEL7 VM. For small tasks, it is working fine but for a long-running process which exceeds 1hour 30 minutes. az vm-run-command timed out. But in the background, I can see ansible-playbook is still running as a process. az vm run-command exactly timed out in 1 hour 30 minutes every time.

> Error : ERROR: Deployment failed. Correlation ID:
>   aed2e89a-9500-4836-9221-9eef8f05bee2. Provisioning of VM extension
>   'RunCommandLinux' has timed out. Extension installation may be taking
>   too long, or extension status could not be obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your description of the issue, the task that executes ansible command is running in the background and the run command task exceed 1 hour and 30 minutes.

Then there are two possible reasons should pay attention to. **One** is that the maximum time a script can run is 90 minutes, after which it will time out, so you need to make sure the ansible task does not execute more than 90 minutes. **Another** is that outbound connectivity from the VM is required to return the results of the script. It depends on port 443, so you need to check if the port 443 is blocked in the outbound.

For more details, see [Restrictions of Run Command in VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command#restrictions). In addition, if it gives the error about the authentication, you should make sure which user do you execute the ansible in the VM and how to set the authentication.

If you have more questions, please give me the messages. I'm glad to provide more help:-)

Comment: Thanks Charles for providing the restriction about Run Command information. I am working with Azure support team for any workaround and created GIt issue with Azure cli team for increasing timed out .  Here is the issue : https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/8967